# VBA Outlook On Send Event Check Recipients for Custom Form

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I've written outlook macros before that will check recipients prior to sending through a send event in the "ThisOutlookSession" of Visual Basic in Outlook. I've recently created a custom Meeting Form called "ResearchMeeting" and want to write a macro for send events of only this form type.

I suppose basically i'm asking how to check whether the form type of the meeting being sent is a "ResearchMeeting".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.FormDescription - as I am not using Special forms myself I am not sure, but you might find the form somewhere in there.

If not: I guess that your form adds data to special fields, that do not exist (or are at least not used) in the normal Meeting-form. Therefore I think it would be best to check, if one of these fields is not nothing (or not the datatype that it would beb if used).

I hope  one of these hints helps.
Max

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll give those a shot and let you know!